# Trying to get a nested if statement to work

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to make it so that when I enter the correct word value into the text box it will return the words defined by the message variable and when the words do not match it gives the opposite message. The problem I am having is that nothing happens at all when I enter the values either correctly or incorrectly and press the button.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
  <title>Login</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckCredentials() {
      var username = parseFloat(document.getElementById("userbox").value);
      var password = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pwdbox").value);
      var message = "";
      username = document.getElementById("userBox").value;
      password = document.getElementById("pwdBox").value;
      // insert if statement here to check user's credentials
      if (username == 'student' && password == 'cs112') {
        message = "hi";
      } else {
        message = "bye";
      }
      document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = message;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Username: <input type="text" id="userBox" /></p>
  <p>Password: <input type="password" id="pwdBox" /></p>
  <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="CheckCredentials();" />
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When testing equality in your if statement you want to be using the `==` operator rather than the `=` assignment operator: `if (username == student && password == cs112) {...}`

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: why `parseFloat` for getting a string?

Comment: Ok, I see that mistake and why that would affect the likelihood of it working but it still doesn't work or return anything? I don't even get an error message and parsefloat is how we were taught how to do it with numbers, is there a better one?

Comment: please add the html part as well.

Comment: `password == cs112`, what is cs112? I'm assuming that should be a string.

Comment: Always check your dev tools console log for errors. userbox != userBox , strings need to be in quotes. You do not need `username =...` and `password = ...` 2 times... parseFloat is also useless here.

Comment: We are using glitch for this class so that we can easily share it with the professor when we are done and glitch isn't showing any error logs. Also how is parsefloat useless in this scenario?

Comment: **The parseFloat() function parses an argument (converting it to a string first if needed) and returns a floating point number.**  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat  and returns a floating point number.... And yet you are trying to  compare it to a non numeric string.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/fnr64b0h/  You will just get NaN from parseFloat, please read documentation.

Comment: Thank you, removing the parsefloat makes it work in both glitch and there.

Comment: Now I just have to add a portion that says says "fill out the box please" if the boxes are empty

Comment: `if (username == ' || password == '') { alert("empty")}` Also include username with @ to whom you are talking to, so he gets notified, your lucky i stopped.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change the code that people are talking about.